# if I run same program twice which part of memory will be shared

Tags: c, memory, operating-system

I see in one of the career forums above question being asked in interview and I see different answers. It would be great to know what experts at SO say.

I think all the memory will be cleared and it would start afresh on the execution of the first program.

Comment: can someone point what is wrong with question to downvote it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

none of the virtual memory will be shared.

The loader 'may' re-use the same physical memory pages 
and it 'may' re-use some of the physical memory pages
and it 'may' not re-use any of the physical memory pages.

It all depends on the current 'memory load'

Do you understand the concepts of 'mapped' memory pages and 'virtual' addresses?  How about 'virtual' memory? How about the concept of 'working set' of memory pages?

Overall, these concepts result in:

The address of your program in the physical memory is not deterministic.

The address of your program in the virtual address space will probably be the same from one execution to the next.

Comment: Last sentence could be false because of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)

Comment: Yes - at high level I have read on the topic mentioned by you. So I were to summarize what I understood from above answers is 1) address of program in Virtual address space could be same from one run to next if no ASLR is there ?

Answer (score 0):

The only reasonable answer to this question is:
"This question has no reasonable answer. The short answer is:'Nothing.', which is more or less true, depending on the underlying hardware and operating system - if there is actually one, which isn't necessary. For the C language itself, if this is a C language question, only memory that is declared static or has an explicit initializer, will have values set when it starts, so any other variable has a theoretical chance of containing values from a previous run."

> I think all the memory will be cleared

The interviewer might fish for such an answer. Who would clear it and why?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this entirely depends upon the operating system. Some systems have mechanisms for processes running the same application (or library) to share the same copy. Others do not.

Older multi-user systems were better equipped for this than the systems more common today.

Answer (score 0):

If it is executed simultaneously (assuming same program running), Text region (containing the code bits) most probably is shared. This is because though the virtual address of the two process are different, but the mapping to the text region in kernel can be shared to the next execution of the same binary. 
The other regions of the program like data, stack etc are unique to the process execution instances which are not shared.